# Integral closure in the total ring of fractions of reduced ring. Is it finitely generated?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R = \bigoplus_{i = 0}^\infty R_i$ be a reduced finitely generated graded $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, $R_0 = \mathbb{C}$. Let $\overline{R}$ be the integral closure of $R$ in its total ring of fractions. Is $\overline{R}$ finitely generated as an $R$-module? When $R$ is a domain, this is a consequence of Noether's theorem.

Comment: It is easy to reduce to the domain case.